Does logsSubscribe only send notifications when the mentions address is logged?
https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/logssubscribe
I was looking through this and I saw
mentions: [  ] - array containing a single Pubkey (as base-58 encoded string); if present, subscribe to only transactions mentioning this address
The wording here isn't clear. Does the address I set as the mentions parameter need to be logged, or can it just be involved in the transaction?

According to the document, the address you set as the mentions parameter does not need to be logged, it just needs to be involved in the transaction. Specifically, the document says "subscribe to only transactions mentioning this address".
